# Ubuntu 13.04 won't boot after new AMD catalyst center

Tags: boot, drivers, ati, catalyst

I am far from an experienced linux user.  I uninstalled the latest catalyst center and installed the new AMD beta driver.  The installation seemed to go fine then it said I should restart to avoid instability.  I restarted and then the purple screen comes up for a second, some message flashes too quickly for me to read.  Then it goes into a black screen with the blinking cursor.  Nothing I type on the keyboard registers.  I've looked up and down for solutions but everything I've found about boot problems says I need to get into the terminal and type commands.... I can't even get there.  I tried holding shift while computer was booting as I saw that in a thread saying it will help load some sort of safe mode.  What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

If your system has Grub BootLoader, you can choose Linux 3.x...(etc) RECOVERY MODE) this will get you into a safemode-like way.

Comment: I don't know if my system has that.  How would I get to that prompt from boot up? (Right after mobo screen)

Comment: When you first boot the system, is there a screen allowing you to choose an OS, (typically between linux and windows, or linux and another linux distro) Or does it just boot straight to ubuntu?

Comment: Straight to Ubuntu